# how to work with array updates

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am looking for some inspiration from someone wiser than me with PHP/MySQL.

In have a database application, and in this instance there are two primary tables and one child table.

Primary Table 1 - Documents
Primary Table 2 - JobDesriptions
Child Table - LnkDocuments_JobDescriptions, which as the title suggests is a one to many relational table between the Document and Job Description Table.  In my Documents Table I have a field which is a lookup of JobDescriptions and presents options as a checkbox, this field is called 'AppliesTo', because of the way the application works, the field stores the results as a string, eg "1,2,3,4,5)  I have used the explode function to turn this into an array and then insert each record into the child table, as I prefer 1-2-many relationships.  This is the code that I have, and it works.

```
$jdarray = explode(',',$values['AppliesTo']);

foreach($jdarray as $item)
{
$sql2 = "INSERT INTO LnkDocuments_JobDescriptions (DocumentFk, JobDescriptionFk) 
values ('".$keys["DocumentPk"]."', '$item')"; CustomQuery($sql2);
}
```

The problem I now have is that if that table gets updated, I need to also update the child table, i have tried this code (but quickly realised that it is wrong):

```
$jdarray = explode(',',$values['AppliesTo']);

foreach($jdarray as $item)
{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM LnkDocuments_JobDescriptions WHERE DocumentFk='".$keys["DocumentPk"]."' AND JobDescriptionFk='$item'"; ;
    $num_rows = mysql_num_rows(CustomQuery($sql));

    if ($num_rows > 0) //Delete Record
        {
            $sql2 = "DELETE FROM LnkDocuments_JobDescriptions WHERE DocumentFk='".$keys["DocumentPk"]."' AND JobDescriptionFk='$item'"; CustomQuery($sql2);
            echo "JD FK : ".$item." deleted";
        }
    else  //Insert Record
        {
            $sql3 = "INSERT INTO LnkDocuments_JobDescriptions (DocumentFk, JobDescriptionFk) 
            values ('".$keys["DocumentPk"]."', '$item')"; CustomQuery($sql3);   
            echo "JD FK : ".$item." added";
        }

}
```

It occured to me that I need to compare differences in the arrays, but havent got a clue how to do this, but this is what I need:

If I can get $oldarray and $new array to compare, for example

if in old array there were values 1,2,3,4 and in $newarray there were values 1,2,3,5, I want the code to loop through each value to determine if there is a change, e.g. if value exists in old and new array then do nothing, if value exists in old array but not new then delete, if value exists in new array but not old then insert.

I have also thought about just deleting all associated records and adding again, but think this is bad practice and will result in high number primary key, also it is worth noting that in my example there are only 5 options, this is just for testing, in reality there could be dozens.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I didn't look thoroughly at all your code but it seems to me it should work. What exactly is the issue?

Comment: the problem with the code I have used is that it doesnt compare differences, it will insert new records ok, but it will also delete ALL records IF they already exist, not taking into account whether they have been removed in new array

Comment: I think I see what you are trying to achieve, thanks.

Comment: I think you are making life difficult for yourself. If you are deleting a row from a primary table you should know at that point in time which Link row to delete. You will have one of the KEYS required to do the tidyup of the link table at the same time. All this array processing means you have missed the obvious

Comment: I am not deleting from the primary table, i am deleted the associated record from the child table.

Comment: In your `for` loop, is `$item` numeric or is it a string?

Comment: Ok so something must have initialted this process, So you should know at least one of the KEYS that you can use to delete the link row

Comment: if you do not want to delete already existing rows which are still active, i suggest you select * from link table and in the cycle compare rows with $item var. this comparation will result into inserting or deleting (or doing nothing) row in db.

Comment: Hi Jimmmy that sounds good, but could you please put it in an example code so I can try and understand why you mean?  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to optimize things I'm not sure that reading the values already present in the table and then deleting only those are not in the new version while inserting the missing records is the best way to go. In my opinion it would be much faster to just delete everything in one query, then insert all records in one query. Try something like this:

```
$item_list = implode( ',' , $jdarray );
$delete_query = "DELETE FROM LnkDocuments_JobDescriptions WHERE DocumentFk='".$keys["DocumentPk"]."' AND JobDescriptionFk IN ( $item_list )";
CustomQuery($delete_query);

$document_key = "'" . $keys["DocumentPk"] . "'";
$item_list_to_insert = "($document_key, " . implode( "), ($document_key, ", $jdarray ) . ")";

$insert_query = "INSERT INTO LnkDocuments_JobDescriptions (DocumentFk, JobDescriptionFk) VALUES " . $item_list_to_insert;
CustomQuery($insert_query);
```

**Note**: I didn't test this, there might some debugging needed.

Comment: I did think about deleting everything in child table that was linked to that record and adding again based on new value, but isnt that bad practice?

Comment: Not at all, in fact it is standard practice if the resulting queries can be executed faster, which is the case for most database setups. Usually the query round time is more of a factor than the query execution time so you should seek to minimize the number of queries you run. And that's not including the processing time for the loop.

Comment: ok I have put that code in and it does work, but one of the reasons I want to do it this way, is later I would like to expand on the code to email subscribed users of changes.

Comment: And you want to be able to specify the exact number of changes made? That should have been part of your question as it changes the question from performance to user friendliness. Maybe accept this answer and open another question where you explain why you want to compare?